Python array sorting price incorrectly
I have made an array with a description and price but can't seem to get the sortign to sort by price. Can someone assist or guide me on why this isn't sorting by price correctly? I have checked the type fro price and it is a float. From what I understand, it should be working. I am not getting an error either. However the output is not sorted by price. :/
Build the array
import array 
newlist = []
for d in products:
    desc =d.description
    price=d.price
    #print(type(price))
    newlist.append(f"{desc}:{price}")

newlist output
['Coors Light American-style Light Lager Beer:16.99', 'Coors Light American-style Light Lager Beer:26.99', 'Michelob ULTRA Superior Light Domestic Lager Beer:18.99', 'Samuel Adams Summer Ale Seasonal Beer:19.99', 'Miller Lite American Pilsner Light Lager Beer:22.99', 'Miller Lite American Pilsner Light Lager Beer:26.99', 'Michelob ULTRA Superior Light Domestic Lager Beer:26.99', 'Bud Light Lager Beer:32.99', 'Samuel Adams Summer Ale Seasonal Beer:10.99', 'Michelob ULTRA Superior Light Domestic Lager Beer:33.99', 'Busch Light Domestic Lager Beer:31.99', 'Michelob ULTRA Superior Light Domestic Lager Beer:26.99', 'Coors Banquet American Lager Beer:16.99', 'Stella Artois Premium Lager Beer:20.99', 'Michelob ULTRA Superior Light Domestic Lager Beer:34.99', "Leinenkugel's Summer Shandy Craft Beer:19.99", 'Coors Light American-style Light Lager Beer:22.99', 'Blue Moon Belgian-Style Ale White Wheat Beer:19.99', 'Blue Moon Belgian-Style Ale White Wheat Beer:19.99', 'Heineken Original Lager Beer, 12 Pack, 12 fl oz Bottles:20.99']

Try to sort by price
import operator
getcount = itemgetter(int(1))
list(map(getcount, newlist))
sortedlist = sorted(newlist, key=getcount)

for l in sortedlist:
    print(l)

Output
Samuel Adams Summer Ale Seasonal Beer:10.99
Leinenkugel's Summer Shandy Craft Beer:19.99
Heineken Original Lager Beer, 12 Pack, 12 fl oz Bottles:20.99
Michelob ULTRA Superior Light Domestic Lager Beer:18.99
Miller Lite American Pilsner Light Lager Beer:22.99
Miller Lite American Pilsner Light Lager Beer:26.99
Michelob ULTRA Superior Light Domestic Lager Beer:26.99
Michelob ULTRA Superior Light Domestic Lager Beer:33.99
Michelob ULTRA Superior Light Domestic Lager Beer:26.99
Michelob ULTRA Superior Light Domestic Lager Beer:34.99
Blue Moon Belgian-Style Ale White Wheat Beer:19.99
Blue Moon Belgian-Style Ale White Wheat Beer:19.99
Dos Equis Mexican Lager Beer, 12 Pack, 12 fl oz Bottles:19.99
Coors Light American-style Light Lager Beer:16.99
Coors Light American-style Light Lager Beer:26.99
Coors Banquet American Lager Beer:16.99
Coors Light American-style Light Lager Beer:22.99
Stella Artois Premium Lager Beer:20.99
Bud Light Lager Beer:32.99
Busch Light Domestic Lager Beer:31.99


itemgetter(int(1)) This is the same as itemgetter(1), which gets the second element in the sequence, and since these are strings, it's sorting by the second letter of the string.

Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78643742/238704 which was also lacking in critical details.

Maybe try to sort first, then convert to string:
sortedlist = sorted(products, key=lambda d: d.price)
newlist = []
for d in sortedlist:
    desc =d.description
    price=d.price
    newlist.append(f"{desc}:{price}")
print(newlist)


I would suggest a list comprehension: newlist = [f"{d.description}:{d.price}" for d in sortedlist]
